# Run php code on particular system

Tags: php

According to my requirement i have one php application.I want to run the application on particular system.If it is hosted on server also.Suppose my website is www.xyz.com.This url should be opened from my system only not from other system.

I have tried Following Code

```
$ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$macAddr=false;

#run the external command, break output into lines
$arp=`arp -a $ipAddress`;
$lines=explode("\n", $arp);

#look for the output line describing our IP address
foreach($lines as $line)
{
   $cols=preg_split('/\s+/', trim($line));
   if ($cols[0]==$ipAddress)
   {
       $macAddr=$cols[1];
   }
}
```

How to acheive this

Thanks

Comment: What is `$arp`, it isn't string, it must return `error` !

Comment: Whats the output of `arp -a $ipAddress`

Answer (score 1):

in your .htaccess file, write

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 'write your ip address here'
```